# How to run components in AWS Greengrass?

Tags: aws-iot-greengrass

In [AWS Greengrass Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/create-components.html) it says you can test components like this

```
sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli deployment create \
  --recipeDir ~/greengrassv2/recipes \
  --artifactDir ~/greengrassv2/artifacts \
  --merge "com.example.HelloWorld=1.0.0"
```

But if I want to run a component from another script. I should use the same command? For example I have a component that publishes some data to MQTT, and right now I am using system.os like this:

```
os.system("sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli deployment create \
  --recipeDir ~/greengrassv2/recipes \
  --artifactDir ~/greengrassv2/artifacts \
  --merge "com.example.HelloWorld=1.0.0"")
```

But I am not sure if it's the right solution. It does not seem like a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `greengrass-cli deployment create` command to run the component

1. It's for local development only
2. The command run through all the lifecycle steps defined in the component recipe file before running the component, it can be a big overhead.

If "another script" is also a Greengrass component, you can [Use the AWS IoT Device SDK for interprocess communication (IPC)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/interprocess-communication.html)

If "another script" is not Greengrass component, you can use `restart` command to trigger a run for the component. It's less overhead than `create` command.
`sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli component restart --names "HelloWorld"`